# How to show a horizontal target line on RDLC chart?

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I have a chart created using RDLC. I want to display a dotted line as below which represents target.

[image]

I want to know how to show that dotted line on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably found out, the line control's size does not allow for it to be set dynamically. Here's a workaround solution using a Text Box instead:

> 1. Add the Text Box to the report and resize it to the same width as the chart.
> 2. Set the `CanShrink` property to `True`.
> 3. Use the `StrDup` function in the expression so that it will generate a string of repeated dashes equal to the target value, for example:
>      `=StrDup(CountRows("ReportItemsDataSet"),"-")`
> 4. Lastly, experiment with the Font name and weight so that the size of the text box matches the chart. You may need to adjust the # of characters if it is too long and wraps. This could be done using division or subtracting a constant value to shorten the string.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add a second column to your data set (e.g. called target), with each value set to 95% (or whatever).

Then, add this as a second data field to your chart and format it as a line.